# Play audio response from OpenAI TTS API in React Native with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, mp3, text-to-speech, expo-av

I've recently started to develop a React Native App with Expo and a couple of days ago I ran into a problem which is now beginning to make me crazy.

I want to send a text string to OpenAI TTS API and play the audio response in my app immediately. I don't want to save the file locally. Link to API: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-to-speech

So far I have successfully made the HTTP request and it looks like I get the correct response from the API. When I output `response.blob()` I get:

`{"_data": {"__collector": {}, "blobId": "5C362F63-71CB-45EC-913E-9A808AF2194F", "name": "speech.mp3", "offset": 0, "size": 143520, "type": "audio/mpeg"}}`

The issue seems to be to play the sound with expo-av. I have been Googling for days now, and no matter which solution I try, I get some error when trying to play the sound. The current error with the current code is:

Error: The AVPlayerItem instance has failed with the error code -1002 and domain "NSURLErrorDomain".

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me (please write code examples).

I also read this post where the solution was to switch to Google's TTS API, but that is not the solution I want:
https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/13pa9wx/playing_blob_audio_using_expo_audio_react_native/

This is my code:

```
const convertTextToSpeech = async (textToConvert) => {

    const apiKey = 'myKey';
    const url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/speech';

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            model: 'tts-1',
            input: textToConvert,
            voice: 'alloy',
            language: 'da',
        })
    };

    await fetch(url, requestOptions)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            return response.blob();
        })
        .then(blob => {
            playSound(blob);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('There was a problem with the request:', error);
        });
};

async function playSound(blob) {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({ uri: url });
    await sound.playAsync();
}
```

Comment: Joining the question. I am trying the same with Axios and running into issues as well when trying to parse the blob somehow and play it with expo-av in react native development.

Comment: I managed something with this:

`try {
    const mp3 = await openai.audio.speech.create({
      model: "tts-1",
      voice: "alloy",
      input: "Hello",
    });

    const mp3Stream = new PassThrough();
    mp3Stream.end(Buffer.from(await mp3.arrayBuffer()));
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="speech.mp3"');
    mp3Stream.pipe(res);`

my personal issue is how to parse this on the client side to a Blob or URL with React Native Expo because the usual methods don't work. If you know, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after some serious attempts trying to figure this out, this is my solution, I hope it serves you and others well. Works for me for now (I am still testing functionality so it might run into issues down the road but fingers crossed).

- adopted from https://nickjones.tech/buffer-blob-managed-expo/.
- You'll need to install `react-native-buffer` before you implement it.

Also I haven't handled the sound instance much more than just playing it to make sure it works, so expecting more work there probably..

**Client**

```js
    const toBuffer = async (blob) => {
      const uri = await toDataURI(blob);
      const base64 = uri.replace(/^.*,/g, "");
      return Buffer.from(base64, "base64");
    };

    const toDataURI = (blob) =>
      new Promise((resolve) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onloadend = () => {
          const uri = reader.result?.toString();
          resolve(uri);
        };
      });

    const constructTempFilePath = async (buffer) => {
      const tempFilePath = FileSystem.cacheDirectory + "speech.mp3";
      await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(
        tempFilePath,
        buffer.toString("base64"),
        {
          encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
        }
      );

      return tempFilePath;
    };
```

and

```js
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const buffer = await toBuffer(blob);
    const tempFilePath = await constructTempFilePath(buffer);
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({ uri: tempFilePath });
    await sound.playAsync();
```

**Server**

```js
    const mp3 = await openai.audio.speech.create({
      model: "tts-1",
      voice: "alloy",
      input: "Hello World",
    });

    const mp3Stream = new PassThrough();
    mp3Stream.end(Buffer.from(await mp3.arrayBuffer()));
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="audio.mp3"');
    mp3Stream.pipe(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried it, but when I install and import react-native-buffer I get the following error: 

'JSI bindings were not installed for react-native-fast-base64 module'.
 
Does this error tell you anything?

Comment: It works now - thank you so much!! Maybe I misunderstood you, but I had to change the function toBuffer:

const toBuffer = async (blob) => {
    const Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer;
    const uri = await toDataURI(blob);
    const base64 = uri.replace(/^.*,/g, "");
    return Buffer.from(base64, "base64");
};

Comment: yes if you do it server side you can do `require`. glad it helped you! :)